# How to find probability

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Consider this question:

Mean of $X$ is 20 and upper bound is 50. If $X$ changes daily with mean 0 and variance 1, independently of the other days. If today $X=40$ what can you say about the probability that $X$ will be between 35 and 45 after 5 days. 
ChebyChev is supposed to be used for this. I am unsure of how to use it. If the mean is 20 and the value is 40 then tomorrow mean will be 20 and variance would be increased by 1. So, whatever variance is today it will be 5 times, 5 days from now.  So, P(35 <= X <= 45) = P(X - 20 >= 5*var) = 1/25.
Is this correct?

Comment: "Looks like standard normal RV" Yes, somehow it does. But it is not mentioned in the text.

Comment: Can I solve it using ChebyChev or Chernoff? What would be the steps taken further?

Comment: I don't think an inequality is what you need here. Inequality will give you a bound, but not the exact answer.

Answer (score 1):

The sum of independent Gaussian RVs is a Gaussian RV with a variance that is the sum of the individual variances, and a mean that is the sum of the means.  From this, the PDF of values on the last day is immediately available.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think this question want you to point out that the probability of X = 40 in today does not affect the probability of X in the next 5 days. Because it is independently of the other days.

So, if the distribution of X is standard normal distribution, then you can compute the $P(35<=X<=45)$ directly.

Comment: The changes from day to day are independent, which does not make the values on each day independent.

Comment: Do you think it canbe solved using any inequality (Markov, chebychev, chernoff)